# How to install .exe as cron job or scheduled task? C#

Tags: winforms, installation, scheduled-tasks, cron

I have a small program that I would like to turn into an installable windows.form. It needs to automatically be run as a cron job/scheduled task. How can I do this?

**C#**

Answer (score 0):

You can either have it setup as a Windows Service or the `at` command can run it as a scheduled task.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

Comment: Windows Services cannot show a form as they don't have a desktop available.